# How do I check whether token expired or not after user clicks on forgot password link in email

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to implement very simple forgot password functionality within my React/Node app.

I understand the following part.

1) User forgets password initiates request by entering email address. 
2) Database verifies if email exists, if it does, send email with password reset link. In the link contains the route for encoded email along with special token.

Example Reset Link Request:

http://localhost:5855/forgotpasswordpage/eEJvdW5EDD1Y4Q/eyJhbGciOiJGcJhbJhb

Where the first param is the base64 encoded email and the second is JWT token.

What I'm stuck on is how do you verify that the token is still valid or not after the person has clicked on the link? Because right now, any user in my application can go to the special URL and reset there password without an expiration.

Here is my code.

**Reset Password Request**

```html
import React from "react";
import forgotService from "../../services/forgotpasswordService";
import { Form, Input, Button, Row } from "antd";
import Base64 from "base-64";

class Forgotpassword extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: false,
      successMsg: false
    };
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.props.form.validateFields(async (err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        var data = {
          email: values.email,
          emailEncode: Base64.encode(values.email)
        };

        //Check if user is in the db.
        const forgotcheckuserData = await forgotService.forgotcheckUser(data);

        if (forgotcheckuserData.length === 0) {
          this.setState({
            errorMsg: true
          });

          this.props.form.resetFields();
        } else {
          this.setState({
            errorMsg: false,
            successMsg: true
          });

          this.props.form.resetFields();

          const forgotpasswordData = await forgotService.emailUser(data);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    return (
      <div className="form-container">
        <div className="forgotpasswordContainer">
          {/* User does not exist */}
          {this.state.errorMsg === true ? (
            <span style={{ color: "red" }}>
              That email address does not exist in our system.
            </span>
          ) : null}
          {/* Success. Send forgot password email */}
          {this.state.successMsg === true ? (
            <span style={{ color: "green" }}>
              Success. Please check your email to reset your password.
            </span>
          ) : null}
          <Form layout="inline" onSubmit={e => this.onSubmit(e)}>
            <Row>
              <Form.Item>
                {getFieldDecorator("email", {
                  rules: [
                    { type: "email", message: "That is not a valid email!" },
                    {
                      required: true,
                      message: "Please put in an email address"
                    }
                  ]
                })(<Input placeholder="Email Address" />)}
              </Form.Item>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <Button type="primary" id="loginButton" htmlType="submit">
                Submit
              </Button>
            </Row>
          </Form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const ForgotWrapper = Form.create({ name: "forgot_form" })(Forgotpassword);

export default ForgotWrapper;
```

**BackEnd**

```js
var db = require("../dbconnection");
var forgotpasswordMail = require("./Forgotpasswordmail");
var SHA256 = require("sha256");
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var inlineCss = require("nodemailer-juice");
var jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

var forgotPassword = {
  forgotcheckUser: function(data, callback) {
    db.query("select * from users where email=?", [data.email], callback);
  },
  forgotAuth: function(data, callback) {
    var datetime = new Date();
    var dateModified =
      datetime.getFullYear() +
      "-" +
      (datetime.getMonth() + 1) +
      "-" +
      datetime.getDate();
    var password = SHA256(data.password);
    var confirmPassword = SHA256(data.confirmPassword);
    console.log(data);
    db.query(
      "UPDATE users set password=?, confirmpassword=?, dateModified=? WHERE email=?",
      [password, confirmPassword, dateModified, data.emailId]
    );
  },
  emailUser: function(data, callback) {
    var resetToken = jwt.sign(
      {
        data: data.email,
        exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 60 // 1 hour
      },
      "secretToken"
    );

    var emailData = {
      email: data.email,
      emailEncoded: data.emailEncode,
      resetpasswordToken: resetToken
    };

    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: "gmail",
      auth: {
        user: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        pass: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      },
      // TLS is for localhost only, disable once on production.
      tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        debug: true
      }
    });
    let mailOptions = {
      from: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      to: data.email,
      subject: "Forgot Password Request",
      html: forgotpasswordMail.forgotTemplate(emailData)
    };
    // Nodemailer Juice Configuration Options
    transporter.use("compile", inlineCss(mailOptions));
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
      }
    });
  }
};

module.exports = forgotPassword;
```

**Reset Password Page (After user clicks on password reset link.)**

```js
import React from "react";

import forgotService from "../../services/forgotpasswordService";
import Base64 from "base-64";

import { Form, Button, Row, Col, Icon, Tooltip, Input } from "antd";
import { PasswordInput } from "antd-password-input-strength";

import Headericons from "../common/header-icons";
import Header from "../common/header";
import Footer from "../common/footer";

class Forgotpasswordemail extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      emailId: Base64.decode(this.props.match.params.id),
      password: "",
      confirmPassword: "",
      capslockEnabled: false,
      errorMsg: false,
      errorMsg2: false,
      successMsg: false
    };
  }

  compareToFirstPassword = (rule, value, callback) => {
    const { form } = this.props;
    if (value && value !== form.getFieldValue("password")) {
      callback("Two passwords that you enter is inconsistent!");
    } else {
      callback();
    }
  };

  validateToNextPassword = (rule, value, callback) => {
    const { form } = this.props;
    if (value && this.state.confirmDirty) {
      form.validateFields(["confirm"], { force: true });
    }
    callback();
  };

  async onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.props.form.validateFields(async (err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        const emailId = Base64.decode(this.props.match.params.id);

        // const data = {
        //   emailId: emailId,
        //   password: values.password,
        //   confirmPassword: values.confirmPassword
        // };

        //const forgotpasswordData = await forgotService.forgotAuth(data);

        this.props.form.resetFields();
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.match.params);
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid" id="forgotpasswordemail">
        <Headericons />
        <Header />
        <div className="container">
          <div className="genericcontainer">
            <h1>RESET YOUR PASSWORD</h1>
            {/* Not identical passwords */}
            {this.state.errorMsg2 !== false ? (
              <span id="forgotunique" style={{ color: "red" }}>
                Passwords are not the same.
              </span>
            ) : null}
            {/* Success. Change users password */}
            {this.state.successMsg !== false ? (
              <span id="forgotunique" style={{ color: "green" }}>
                Password Successfully Changed.
              </span>
            ) : null}
            <div className="forgotpasswordContainer">
              <Form layout="inline" onSubmit={e => this.onSubmit(e)}>
                <Row type="flex" justify="center">
                  <Form.Item>
                    <Input
                      prefix={
                        <Icon
                          type="user"
                          style={{ color: "rgba(0,0,0,.25)" }}
                        ></Icon>
                      }
                      disabled
                      value={this.state.emailId}
                    />
                  </Form.Item>
                </Row>
                <Row type="flex" justify="center">
                  <Form.Item>
                    {getFieldDecorator("password", {
                      rules: [
                        {
                          required: true,
                          message: "Please enter a new password"
                        },
                        {
                          required: true,
                          pattern:
                            "^(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+*!=]).*$",
                          message:
                            "Password must contain 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase and 1 special character"
                        },
                        {
                          required: true,
                          min: 8,
                          message: "Password must be 8 characters or longer"
                        },
                        {
                          validator: this.validateToNextPassword
                        }
                      ]
                    })(
                      <PasswordInput
                        prefix={
                          <Icon
                            type="lock"
                            style={{ color: "rgba(0,0,0,.25)" }}
                          ></Icon>
                        }
                        placeholder="Password"
                      />
                    )}
                  </Form.Item>
                </Row>
                <Row type="flex" justify="center">
                  <Form.Item>
                    {getFieldDecorator("confirmPassword", {
                      rules: [
                        {
                          required: true,
                          message: "Please confirm your password!"
                        },
                        {
                          validator: this.compareToFirstPassword
                        }
                      ]
                    })(
                      <PasswordInput
                        prefix={
                          <Icon
                            type="lock"
                            style={{ color: "rgba(0,0,0,.25)" }}
                          ></Icon>
                        }
                        placeholder="Confirm Password"
                      />
                    )}
                  </Form.Item>
                </Row>
                <Row type="flex" justify="center">
                  <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" id="resetButton">
                    Reset Password
                  </Button>
                </Row>
              </Form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const ForgotPasswordWrapper = Form.create({ name: "forgot_password_form" })(
  Forgotpasswordemail
);

export default ForgotPasswordWrapper;
```

Comment: When you generate the JWT you must associate that with the email in some way, right? If so, then when the user resets their password, can you send the JWT back down and mark that as completed? You can also set an expiration date/time on the JWT that can get checked once it is sent down.